# Computing $x_3$ using the secant method

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods

So given the function $f=x^2-1=0$, we must use secant method to find a root, I also have $x_1=-1+\epsilon, x_2=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. I am to prove $x_3=-1-\epsilon$

$f(x_1)=-2\epsilon+\epsilon^2, f(x_2)=\frac{\epsilon^2}{4}-1$
By the secant method $x_3=x_2-f(x_2)\frac{x_2-x_1}{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}$

So $x_3=\epsilon/2-(\frac{\epsilon^2}{4}-1)\bigg(\frac{\frac{\epsilon}{2}-(-1-\epsilon)}{(\frac{\epsilon^2}{4}-1)-(-2\epsilon+\epsilon^2)}\bigg)$

But this now seems unsimplifiable to me and out of the ball park of the expected solution

Comment: Could you please correct the mistakes in your question, for example, if $f(x) = x^2 - 1$, then $f(-1+\epsilon) = \epsilon^2 - 2\epsilon$

Comment: I fixed the $f(x_1)$ please let me know if there are more mistakes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As G.Gare mentioned, you have a few mistakes.

Correcting them and simplifying, you should get
$$x_3=\frac{(\epsilon -1) \epsilon +2}{3 \epsilon -2}$$ Since $\epsilon$ is supposed to be small, use the long division or Taylor series to get
$$x_3=-1-\epsilon -2 \epsilon ^2+O\left(\epsilon ^3\right)=-1-\epsilon +O\left(\epsilon ^2\right)$$

Comment: I’m not familiar with long division of Taylor Series how would you get from your first expression to the latter?

Comment: Almost as @LutzL wrote, add and subtract $(-1-\epsilon)$ to get $x_3=-1-\epsilon-\frac{4 \epsilon ^2}{2-3 \epsilon}$

Comment: When i did long division i got $\frac{\epsilon}{3} + \frac{16}{9(3\epsilon - 2)} - \frac{1}{9}$ and wasnt sure where to proceed from there.

Comment: @DillainSmith. You have to do the division by increasing powers that is to say divide $(2-\epsilon+\epsilon^2)$ by $(-2+3\epsilon)$ and not what you did that is to say divide $(\epsilon^2-\epsilon+2)$ by $(3\epsilon-2)$

Comment: What you said makes sense completely now I understand. Thanks very much!

Comment: @DillainSmith. This is good to know and you are welcome !

Answer (score 1):

With a concrete equation, you can simplify the quotient by canceling $x_2-x_1$, as
\begin{align}
x_3=x_2-f(x_2)\frac{x_2-x_1}{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}
&=x_2-(x_2^2-1)\frac{x_2-x_1}{x_2^2-x_1^2}\tag1\\
&=x_2-\frac{x_2^2-1}{x_2+x_1}=\frac{x_2x_1+1}{x_2+x_1}\tag2
\end{align}
Only then insert the values into the simplified expression
\begin{align}
x_3=\frac{\fracϵ2(-1+ϵ)+1}{-1+\frac{3ϵ}2}
=-\frac{1-\fracϵ2+\frac{ϵ^2}2}{1-\frac{3ϵ}2}
&= -1-ϵ\,\frac{1+\fracϵ2}{1-\frac{3ϵ}2}\tag3\\
&=-1-ϵ\,\left(1+\frac{2ϵ}{1-\frac{3ϵ}2}\right)\tag4
\end{align}
etc.

Comment: For your simplified $x_3$ expression, how do you get from the left side to the right side essentially?

Comment: (1) is just inserting, (2) is the binomial formula and fraction manipulation. (3) is again inserting and polynomial division. One could also employ the geometric series.

Comment: 1 and 2 i understand its (3) where I dont know how you got from the LHS to RHS (maybe im not seeing something). And how would you get that into the final form $-1-\epsilon+\mathcal{O}(\epsilon^2)$?

Comment: I added two more steps. You just need to expand into a normal form for polynomials and then apply polynomial division with remainder.